# Busy Waiting with semaphores in win32

Tags: winapi

I wan't to implement a barrier.To do so I do a busy waiting until the value of the semaphore is 0.

I've managed to do this on POSIX using the value of the semaphore. Is there any way to do this in Windows ?

Comment: Please don't busy wait.  http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/06/05/in-praise-of-idleness/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a simple integer with a busy loop.  Use an actual semaphore object via [`CreateSemaphore()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682438.aspx), and use [`WaitForSingleObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032.aspx) (or related function) to tell you when the semaphore is in a state to pass through your barrier.

Comment: I didn't use an integer. I used a semaphore and got it's value with sem_getvalue

Comment: I've tried WaitForSingleObject($semaphore_handle, INFINITE) but it gets stuck

Comment: You specify the initial and maximum values of the semaphore when you create it, then `WaitForSingleObject()` and `ReleaseSemaphore()` decrement and increment the semaphore's value. There is no way to query a semaphore's current value in Windows. When `WaitForSingleObject()` blocks, you cannot enter the barrier because the semaphore is not in a signaled state, ie its value is 0. You can enter your barrier when the semaphore is in a signaled state, ie its value is greater than 0. [Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686946.aspx) for more details.